# Find the differential Df(0,0)and Df(a,b) for the function f : $R^2 → R^3$ given by $f(x,y)=(xe^y +cosy,x,x+e^y)$.

Tags: calculus

Find the differential Df(0,0)and Df(a,b) for the function f : $R^2 → R^3$ given by $f(x,y)=(xe^y +cosy,x,x+e^y)$.

I'm not sure what this means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what they mean by that, either. To be sure, you need to look it up in your book. But I would guess that they mean the derivative, not the differential. The derivative of a function from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$ is at each point in the domain of $f$ where it exists, a linear function function also from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$ that best approximates the behavior of $f$ at that point. Such linear functions are represented by $m \times n$ matrices, and $Df(a, b)$ is thus the derivative matrix at the point $(a, b)$. This is the matrix of partial derivatives. If $f(x, y) = (f_x, f_y, f_z) \in \Bbb R^3$, then
$$Df =\left [ \begin{matrix} \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial f_z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_z}{\partial y} \end{matrix} \right ]$$
So calculate those partial derivatives, then evaluate them at $(0,0)$ and at $(a, b)$, and build the two matrices.

Comment: Thanks you! I gathered as much as your first paragraph Paul. Sorry my edit didn't come trhough. My actual query was why does go from $R^2 to R^3$

But right now i'm more interest by what you mean by building the **two matrices**. Just to clarify this is just simply plugging (0,0) for the first matrice and (a,b) for the second. With each partial derivative being a column vector.

Comment: $Df$ is a matrix of functions, or equivalently, a function into the set of matrices. $Df(0,0)$ is one matrix of values, and $Df(a,b)$ is another matrix of values. Those are the 2 matrices I was refering to. Once you find what $Df$ is, you evaluate each function at $(0,0)$ to get $Df(0,0)$, and each function at $(a,b)$ to get $Df(a, b)$. As for why $Df(a,b)$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$, this is because it approximates the behavior of $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ near $(a,b)$.

Comment: Each partial derivative is a function from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. Note that it is not $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, but $\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}$, as $f_x$ is a function from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, so is its partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate.